# Python: Array of objects error

Tags: python

I am trying to make an array of columns and rows like this:

[image: rows and columns]

but when I run [my code](https://github.com/johnroper100/CrowdMaster/blob/master/cm_agent_generation/generation.py#L63-L118)

I get

[image: incorrect rows and columns]

why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this question is really suited here, but well…

```
 x = 0
 y = 0
 for row in range(rows):
     x = x + scene.formationArrayColumnMargin
     for ag in range(int(agentsPerRow)):
         y = y + scene.formationArrayRowMargin
```

`y` must be reset to zero each time you run outer `x` loop, otherwise it keeps growing. Something like that:

```
x = 0
for row in range(rows):
    y = 0
    x = x + scene.formationArrayColumnMargin
    for ag in range(int(agentsPerRow)):
        y = y + scene.formationArrayRowMargin
```